# Vercel This Serverless Function has timed out

Tags: node.js, express, serverless, vercel

I have deployed my Express.js server using Vercel serverless service and it was deployed successfully, however every time I use an endpoint it shows me 'This Serverless Function has timed out' error. I checked many videos and the documentation but there is no real solution suggested. The server works perfectly locally when I use Postman and MongoDB atlas but it always shows me this error. What can I do to fix it?

[image]